# How to smoothly show a block with background and text with Angular and ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I'm new in JS and Angular. I try to make ng-show and ng-hide for my background and text. The problem is with my text: I can hide it smoothly, but when it's shown - I get all text first and just then I get my backround. How can I fix it?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: visible;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
}

.ng-hide {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"/>

<div ng-show="myCheck">
    Many text here<br/>
    Many text here<br/>
    Many text here<br/>
    Many text here<br/>
    Many text here<br/>
    Many text here<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a class for your div and use ng-hide transitions to control the animation.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myCheck = false;
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.myClass.ng-hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.myClass.ng-hide-remove,
.myClass.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.myClass.ng-hide-add,
.myClass.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck" />
  <span>{{myCheck?'Hide':'Show'}}</span>

  <div class="myClass" ng-show="myCheck">
    Many text here<br/> Many text here<br/> Many text here<br/> Many text here<br/> Many text here<br/> Many text here<br/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need a slide animation

Comment: @MichaelLev19 feels free to extend CSS however you want. I added a simple sliding animation, but you can add anything you want at this point. Just use ng-hide transitions to be very specific